# DoubleUpDown custom style wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make custom style for doubleupdown button like on example.
Example: [image]
What i have [image]
main problem is that `<RepeatButton x:Name="PART_IncreaseButton" Grid.Row="0" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" Style="{StaticResource CustomRepeatButtonStyle}"/>` does not respond when i am clickin on it why?

Xaml code of me freak:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="customgrid" Background="White">
                        <Polygon x:Name="custompolygon" Points="1,11 6,1 11,11" Fill="SkyBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        </Polygon>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="custompolygon" Property="Fill" Value="black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CustomDoubleUpDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DoubleUpDown}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DoubleUpDown}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Purple">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_IncreaseButton" Grid.Row="0" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" Style="{StaticResource CustomRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_DecreaseButton" Grid.Row="1" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Property=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <xctk:DoubleUpDown Width="180" Height="70" Style="{StaticResource CustomDoubleUpDownStyle}" Value="20"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "...does not respond..."?

Comment: When i am click on repereat button value do not change's

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML there are no functions bound to the click event (or any other event). In other words: From the programs point of view there is nothing to do, when any of your buttons get clicked. Is this your problem?

In this case add event handlers and modify the counter in your model accordingly.

Comment: But "xctk:DoubleUpDown" already has implemetation of click events in toolkit library. And how i think thath it should work through 'x:Name="PART_IncreaseButton"'

Comment: This might be in fact the case, if reflection is used, but at first `x:Name` is only a name.